# Можно ли изменить html код страницы до ее отображения в браузере?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Я делаю расширение для хрома.
Сначала отображается страница, потом начинаются изменения html кода скриптом расширения, а можно ли сделать так, чтобы страница отобразилась только после внесения изменений?
Как я изменяю:
1) Внедряю скрипт в теге head;
1.1) Страница отображается(проблема, которую надо решить)
2) Он скрывает ее с помощью

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.display = "none";
```

3) Изменяю данные;
4) Возвращаю обратно с помощью

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.display = "block";
```

5) И только потом она должна отображаться впервые!

Comment: Да, через php, к примеру. JS начинает работать во время "загрузки (рендеринга)" страницы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сегодня решил эту проблему. В манифесте прописывается:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [
      "\u003Call_urls>"
     ],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start" // Вот это надо написать. И скрипт будет запускаться сразу первым при начале загрузки страницы.
  }
],
 "web_accessible_resources": ["content.js"]
}
```

Затем в контентном скрипте в самом начале пишем:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.display = "none";
```

А после всех необходимых изменений:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.display = "block";
```

И страница отображается снова.

Ну а в фоновой странице:

```
var injection = function() { // Сам скрипт, вводимый в страницу
var pasteScript1; // content.js
pasteScript1 = document.createElement("script1");
pasteScript1.href = chrome.tabs.getURL("content.js");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].insertBefore(pasteScript1);
};

chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { // Инъекция скрипта на страницу
code: "(" + injection.ToString + ")()"
});
```

Comment: Замените `"\u003Call_urls>"` на `"<all_urls>"`

Answer (score 1):

Сначала изменить, а потом отобразить страницу нельзя. Js выполняется на стороне клиента, значит, чтобы браузер исполнил скрипт, ему сначала нужно получить и обработать html-контент, который будет изменён.

Можно попробовать просто скрыть всё и показать после изменения. Не могу гарантировать, что сработает, но попробуйте внедрить в head скрипт, который будет содержать верстку - заглушку (типа preloader), пользователь видит прелоадер, происходят изменения в коде верстки, прелоадер убираем, пользователь видит страницу.

Comment: Да, именно это и есть белый фон document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.display = "none"; Проблема в том, чтобы вообще ничего не было показано до изменений. Пусть браузер загружает страницу, но ничего не показывает. Такое возможно сделать?

Comment: нет, надо создать слой, задать ему фон, фиксированное позиционирование и растянуть на всю страницу, а тегу `body` задать `overflow hidden`. Тогда пользователь не увидит ничего, после обработки - убрать слой и этот стиль.